# a crossing jquery, asp.net and excel issue, trying to export web grid to excel but I cannot hide the dynamic rgPager

Tags: jquery, asp.net, excel, telerik, telerik-grid

I`m trying to export web grid to excel but I cannot hide the dynamic rgPager
this is the jquery code for excel export

```js
  $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id$=Retain]').html()));
        e.preventDefault();
```

it works will but does not hide the pager and this is the telerik grid with dynamic pager:

```
<div class="datagrid PrintArea area1 all" id="Retain">
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="gvProjectType" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" ShowStatusBar="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowMultiRowSelection="True"
            OnNeedDataSource="gvProjectType_NeedDataSource" ClientSettings-AllowExpandCollapse="False" ClientSettings-AllowGroupExpandCollapse="False">
            <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" FirstPageToolTip="الأول" LastPageToolTip="الأخير" NextPagesToolTip="التالى"
                NextPageToolTip="التالى" PageSizeLabelText="عدد العناصر فى الصفحة:" PrevPagesToolTip="السابق" PagerTextFormat="{4} صفحة {0} من {1} ـ العناصر من {2} إلى {3} ـ إجمالي {5} عنصر"
                PrevPageToolTip="السابق" NextPageText="التالى" PrevPageText="السابق" />

            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="TypeId" ClientDataKeyNames="TypeId" Dir="RTL" HierarchyLoadMode="ServerOnDemand" AllowPaging="true" ShowFooter="true"
                NoMasterRecordsText="لا يوجد مشاريع  . " TableLayout="Fixed">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="م">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Container.DataSetIndex + 1 %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle Height="50px" Font-Bold="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="3%" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>


                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TypeName" UniqueName="TypeName" HeaderText="نوع المشروع" FooterText="الاجــمــالـي"
                        ReadOnly="true">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text=""></ModelErrorMessage>
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        <FooterStyle Font-Bold="true"/>
                        <HeaderStyle Height="50px" Font-Bold="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="RequestCount" UniqueName="RequestCount" HeaderText="تحت الطلب" Aggregate="Sum" FooterText=" "
                        ReadOnly="true">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbReportDetails_RequestCount" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RequestProjectsIds") %>' OnCommand="lbReportDetails_Command"><%# Eval("RequestCount") %></asp:LinkButton>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle Font-Bold="true" />
                        <HeaderStyle Height="50px" Font-Bold="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="InProgressCount" UniqueName="InProgressCount" HeaderText="تحت التنفيذ" Aggregate="Sum" FooterText=" "
                        ReadOnly="true">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbReportDetails_InProgressCount" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("InProgressProjectsIds") %>' OnCommand="lbReportDetails_Command"><%# Eval("InProgressCount") %></asp:LinkButton>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle Font-Bold="true" cssClass="hf"/>
                        <HeaderStyle Height="50px" Font-Bold="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>


                     <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="CompletedCount" UniqueName="CompletedCount" HeaderText="منتهي" Aggregate="Sum" FooterText=" "
                        ReadOnly="true">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbReportDetails_CompletedCount" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CompletedProjectsIds") %>' OnCommand="lbReportDetails_Command"><%# Eval("CompletedCount") %></asp:LinkButton>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle Font-Bold="true" />
                        <HeaderStyle Height="50px" Font-Bold="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

              <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="TotalCount" UniqueName="TotalCount" HeaderText="إجمالي" Aggregate="Sum" FooterText=" "
                        ReadOnly="true">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbReportDetails_TotalCount" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TotalProjectsIds") %>' OnCommand="lbReportDetails_Command"><%# Eval("TotalCount") %></asp:LinkButton>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle Font-Bold="true" />
                        <HeaderStyle Height="50px" Font-Bold="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>


                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
            <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" AllowExpandCollapse="False">
                <ClientMessages PagerTooltipFormatString="الصفحة &lt;strong&gt;{0}&lt;/strong&gt;من &lt;strong&gt;{1}&lt;/strong&gt;" />
                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"></Selecting>
                <ClientEvents OnRowSelected="RowActivitiesSelected" OnRowDeselected="RowActivitiesDeselected" />
            </ClientSettings>

            <SortingSettings SortedAscToolTip="الترتيب تصاعدى" SortedDescToolTip="الترتيب تنازلى"
                SortToolTip="إضغط هنا للترتيب" />
            <StatusBarSettings LoadingText="التحميل..." />
        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </div>
```

which never disappear after exporting to excel, except by this code

```js
$('.rgPager').remove();
```

which permanently remove the pager but it is not an option because I need to keep the pager displayed in web page.
Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Have you tried removing the pager div from the HTML string you pass, something like: $('div[id$=Retain]').html().replace("regex here to replace the div", "")

Comment: if you mean this: $('div[id$=Retain]').html().replace(".rgPager", "");
so adding this in general did not work. please note that I need to remove pager in excel only not in web page and i can`t add pager by append function because it is dynamic loaded

Comment: .html() will give you a string, you need to remove the HTML of the pager there and a jQuery selector will not do. You can start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976780/regex-to-remove-html-tags-with-certain-class-from-string

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn`t help